# Magento Custom Button Action results in 404

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller

I am creating a small module that adds a button to the Admin order view page. This button will trigger a custom controller action that will (besides other stuff) create an invoice and shipment.

I have added the button and I can get it to point to my controller action (in theory), adding the current order ID as a paramenter, but clicking the button just gets me to a 404 page.

I have this my config.xml:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <id_acscourier before="Mage_Adminhtml">ID_AcsCourier_Adminhtml</id_acscourier>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

And this is the start of my controller:

```
class ID_AcsCourier_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController
{

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function voucherAction() {
        // more stuff here...
    }
}
```

I am not sure about the config.xml code, I found a sample that suggested this solution after a few hours of reading and searching.
The action is not supposed to produce any kind of output, but I would like to display a message at the end (like the ones magento produces after saving etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Your controller file should be same like below

```
class [namespace]_[module_name]_Adminhtml_[controller_name] extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
     public function indexAction() {
           // your stuff
     }
}
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<unique_tag>
    <title>Manage Controller</title>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <action>adminhtml/[module_name]/[action]</action>
</unique_tag>
```

Comment: I named the controller "ID_AcsCourier_Adminhtml_AcsCourierController" (filename AcsCourierController.php) and put it under the controllers/Adminhtml folder of my module, but the results are the same...

Comment: Please update your full `config.xml` file and your url which are going to `404`

Answer (score 0):

There is a contradiction between your module config.xml and your controller class. There is `_Adminhtml` in your module that would require to point into your admin panel. But your controller is present outside adminhtml. If you are creating a custom module then remove _adminhtml from

```
<modules>
    <id_acscourier before="Mage_Adminhtml">ID_AcsCourier</id_acscourier>
<modules>
```

**Or**
Create the controller inside Adminhtml...

and you are good to go !

Comment: Then change your controller class name. Copy paste me your IndexController.php path, I will tell you the correct class name.

Comment: It's 'ID/AcsCourier/controllers/Adminhtml/' currently the file is named AcsCourierController, as suggested by someone else, but I tried IndexController too...

Comment: In IndexController there is your indexAction that render some layout. Now in  your indexAction add this at first line `echo "working"; exit;` and debug. Then hit url `http://yourdomain.com/id/acscourier/adminhtml/index` if you see the message "working" then all good till your controller.

Comment: Still no go... I am sure I am missing something, but I don't know what it is. I have developed more complex modules than this and none gave me such a hard time...

Comment: If you really want to get it solved, better ask this question in magento.stackexchange.com .There are experts to solve it. Paste the complete code and explain more briefly. Good luck and happy coding.